# How to unlist a list with one value inside a pandas columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame:

```
Id       Col1
1     ['string']
2     ['string2']
```

Is possible to convert the data frame into another data frame that look like this?

```
Id     Col1
1     string
2     string2
```

I tried with this way but only get the `[`.

```
df.col1.apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: ``df.Col1.str[0]``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I tried with this way but only get the [.

Then this means they are `str`ings, not `list`s. You can convert them to `list`s by `apply`ing [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html):

```py
import ast

df.Col1 = df.Col1.apply(ast.literal_eval).explode()
```

to get

```
   Id     Col1
0   1   string
1   2  string2
```